# Why does Skyrim keep wanting to install?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, pc

I've installed Skyrim and registered it with steam. I've tried to run it through steam, from the setup.exe in the disk and the TESV.exe in my steamapps folder but every time it tried to install the game again, then fails.

If Steam is closed, and I try via the disk, it loads the splash screen with an option to run the game but shortly after it just pops up with the install skyrim splash screen.

Why is this happening? How can I get around it?

---

### Edit the First

So I've tried to follow the advice here and renamed my folder (called `VCredist`) which just causes Steam to tell me that skyrim may not have synced with the cloud correctly. I've tried renaming  `installscript.vdf` which also does nothing. I've got **Kaspersky** running, and have had to (due to unrelated shennanigans) **rename my steam folder** steampowered, which is the only remaining thing that might have caused an issue. *Would any of these caused the issue?* Of do you think my **DVD is broken?**

---

### Edit the Second.

Verified my Skyrim files, Uninstalled Skyrim. Uninstalled Steam. Reinstalled Skyrim from disc, letting it install steam in the process. Let it update. Still have the same issue. Will call steam/bethseda today.

### Edit the third.

Here is what the splash screen looks like. Does it give anyone a cluse as to what's wrong? The 'install' button seems wrong.

[image]

Comment: That is rather strange. Have you tried backup up Skyrim, deleting the game and restoring it from the backup?

Comment: When you say let it update. Do you mean Skyrim, Steam or Both? Skyrim will need to update before playing it.

Comment: @Doomsknight I think both updated. Steam certainly did. How can I check skyrim is up todate?

Comment: @Pureferret It should show a downloading status at the bottom of steam when viewing the library, showing the current progress of the download(update). Alternatively, Usually clicking a game that is not up-to-date, it will start the update, and show an ETA message til game is playable. Looking at your 3rd update though, it is a bit baffling. You shouldnt get to the splash screen (via steam) if the game wasnt up to date. Verifying cache should also initialise an update. There must be something else going wrong.

Comment: @Doomsknight It is up to date now. What else might be wrong?

Comment: @Pureferret. Maybe its not trying to install the game, but wants you to infact install dependencies? For example, Direct X. C++ run time, or what ever it requires. What actually happens when you click install again.

Comment: @Doomsknight Nothing, the splashscreen just closes. I'm going to go do what bethseda told me to this morning and see if that helps...

Comment: Good luck. let us know how it turns out :)

Comment: No change! Waiting to hear back from Bethseda!

Comment: I have been having the same issue as well but I think it's the Steam client. It might have not installed a file correctly. After I installed another game it wasn't working and it asked to install a service. I did get it to download and install afterwards, and it seems to be working fine now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only thing that worked was for me to reinstall Windows (!) and then reinstall Steam and Skyrim. The next step that the Bethseda Tech support suggested was to create a new user account, but like I said I skipped that and did a fresh install.

Comment: I have people not wanting to upgrade from xp and you just reinstall to make skyrim run? +1 if only i could up more.

Comment: @Reaces Well, Skyrim is love. Skyrim is life.

Answer (score 1):

My initial suggestion was to run TESV.exe but you've already done that. I'm not sure what is happening here it's rather strange but I have heard of this issue before. The only thing you can try is to backup your save files, delete local content and re-install Skyrim. This *should* fix it for you.

Comment: Good thing I don't have save files as I haven't played skyrim yet!

Comment: I uninstalled (which deleted all local content) then reinstalled it, but no effect.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem.

Instead of running the setup from the disk, open Steam and click the 'Steam' button on the top tab. Choose 'Backup and Restore games' and select the backup location as the disk. This should install the game from the disk without any problem.

If this doesn't work, then your disk is probably corrupted.

Comment: When I try this, I get to the validation window again, and it validates. Then I have the same issue again.

Comment: Try setting Compatibility Mode to different OS's for the steam executable. This helped me when I had validation problems.

Comment: I have no issue with the validation, that works, it just doesn't do anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Steam reads its install status from an installscript.vdf file in the game's steamapps directory. You can try deleting that (after a backup, of course).

Shot in the dark, though.

Comment: After I delete it, it creates a new one and I get back to where I am to start

Comment: You've got to close steam, delete it, and then reopen Steam, for the record. Ah well, was worth a shot.

Comment: That's what I did. Never mind. Will try uninstalling steam next...

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem on my home user account but when I log onto another user account I can play Skyrim just fine. Try using another user account.

Comment: This was actually the next step Bethseda suggested. I'm not sure if it would have worked though.

Comment: This sounds most puzzling.

Answer (score -1):

Check the skyrim folder for a folder named "redist." This is for directx etc. Try renaming that folder to something like redist_BAK.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. Why should this work?